Laravel Reverb + React Native Integration
I've been trying to make this combination work. But it seems that react-native-pusher sdk it not updated to be compatible with laravel reverb yet? Can someone confirm this?
This my sample code.
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import { Pusher } from "@pusher/pusher-websocket-react-native";
export const connectToWebSocket = async () => {
  try {
    const ws = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "reverb",
      Pusher,
      key: "samplekey", // app key
      host: "127.0.0.1",
      wsHost: "127.0.0.1", // host
      wssHost: "127.0.0.1", // host
      wsPort: 8080, // port
      wssPort: 8080,
      enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
      scheme: "https",
    });
    ws.channel({channelName: "sample-channel"});

  } catch (error) {
    console.log("error socket", error);
  }
};

I tried doing sample vue project and implement the same thing but using pusher-js and it's working fine

I had a few issues with configuring this. If you haven't sorted this issue take a look at my post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78648399/laravel-reverb-not-broadcasting-rest-api-with-docker It may help you.

I´m doing something like this:
import { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import Echo from "laravel-echo";
import Pusher from "pusher-js/react-native";
import { REVERB_APP_KEY, REVERB_HOST, REVERB_PORT, REVERB_SCHEME } from "@env";

const useEcho = () => {
  const [echoInstance, setEchoInstance] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    //  Setup Pusher client
    const PusherClient = new Pusher(REVERB_APP_KEY, {
      /**
       * I think the "authorize" is just for SPA Authentication: 
       * https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/sanctum#authorizing-private-broadcast-channels
       * 
        authorizer: (channel) => {
         return {
           authorize: (socketId, callback) => {
             axios
               .post("/api/broadcasting/auth", {
                 socket_id: socketId,
                 channel_name: channel.name,
               })
               .then((response) => {
                 callback(false, response.data);
               })
               .catch((error) => {
                 callback(true, error);
               });
           },
         };
       }, */
      wsHost: REVERB_HOST,
      wsPort: REVERB_PORT ?? 80,
      wssPort: REVERB_PORT ?? 443,
      forceTLS: (REVERB_SCHEME ?? "https") === "https",
      enabledTransports: ["ws", "wss"],
      disableStats: true,
      cluster: {},
    });

    // Create Echo instance
    const echo = new Echo({
      broadcaster: "reverb",
      client: PusherClient,
    });

    setEchoInstance(echo);

    // Cleanup on unmount
    return () => {
      if (echo) {
        echo.disconnect();
      }
    };
  }, []);

  return echoInstance;
};

export default useEcho;

and then something like this:
import useEcho from "../hooks/echo";
...
const echo = useEcho();
....
  useEffect(() => {
    if (echo) {
      // Subscribe to a channel and listen for events
      console.log(``);
      echo.private(`chat.{${user.id}}`).listen("MessageSent", (e) => {
        console.warn("Message received:", e);
      });
    }

    //  Cleanup subscription when component unmounts
    return () => {
      if (echo) {
        echo.leaveChannel("chat");
      }
    };
  }, [echo]);

Try there bro, and then tell me if you got it.
I guess  the connection is working, it's just not subscribing to any channels,
